# Using RewriteBase in .htaccess to make links pretty

Tags: htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm working on a project right now and I'm trying to make the links pretty.

We have urls like this: 
`http://subdomain.domain.com/DynamicCountry/DynamicName/file.php`

What I'm trying to do is set the *RewriteBase* to `/DynamicCountry/DynamicName`. Is this possible using Mod_Rewrite's variables?

Comment: `RewriteBase` is a directive that affects all relative path substitutions in the `RewriteRule` directive. To be honest I don't think this is really what you need. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I assume the "ugly" (real) URL is the one you have given (and which you would need to internally rewrite to)? And what does the "pretty" URL look like? The same but minus the `file.php`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you are happy with pretty URL's that do not end in `/` but have no file extensions shown such as `.php`, for example:
 `http://subdomain.domain.com/DynamicCountry/DynamicName/file`
then you could try this solution.

- Add these lines of code in your `http://subdomain.domain.com/.htaccess` file:

> `RewriteEngine on`
>   `RewriteRule ^(lib|theme|uploads|images|ajax) - [L]`
>   `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|api|theme|images|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)`
>   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

- And then these in your `http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php` file (substituting the `$sPath` variable value with the correct linux path for your hosting environment):

> `<?php`
>   `$sPath='/var/www/subdomain.domain.com/';`
>   `$sAlias=isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])?substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1):'';`
>   `if(strpos($sAlias,'?')>0) $sAlias=substr($sAlias,0,strpos($sAlias,'?'));`
>   `if(strpos($sAlias,'?')<1) $sAlias='default';`
>   `if(!file_exists($sPath.$sAlias.'php')) $sAlias='file-not-found';`
>   `require_once($sPath.$sAlias.'php');`

- And then create a `pages` sub-folder inside the subdomain web root folder, and inside there you could have sub-folders `DynamicCountry` and `DynamicName` and then `file.php`.
  In this example, the pretty URL:
  `http://subdomain.domain.com/DynamicCountry/DynamicName/file`
  would show the page:
  `/var/www/subdomain.domain.com/pages/DynamicCountry/DynamicName/file.php`
- In the event of an HTTP 404 error, you'll need a file to be present at:
  `/var/www/subdomain.domain.com/pages/file-not-found.php`
  in order to ensure an infinite loop of File Not Found errors does not occur! For SEO reasons mainly, remember to use PHP code `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');` before any HTML code is output. This helps search engines identify real pages from error pages.

Obviously you can modify this solution to your requirements but hopefully it gives you a good skeleton concept to work from.